# Scale browser content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, accessibility

Press `cmd` + `+` (or `ctrl` + `+`) to scale up and `cmd` + `-` to scale down page content in your browser. How do I do that with JS? Need this for accessibility settings.

Comment: too broad??? How can one be more specific in this? Have you even read it??

Answer (score 0):

```
zoom: function (percentage) {document.body.style.zoom = percentage + "%";}
```